# Electric field inside open conductor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

Is the electric field zero inside a metal conductor whose surface doesn't enclose a volume ideally, that is, a conductor that is almost a closed surface, except for a small hole?

Comment: If you stick an antenna in through the hole, you can definitely make the field inside the enclosed space non-zero. For example you might do this in a microwave waveguide.

Comment: maybe this wiki article will help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_shielding , it depends on the frequency, there can be holes for higher frequencies that block microwave ones for example

Answer (score 2):

> Is the electric field zero inside ... a conductor that is almost a closed surface, except for a small hole?

No. Consider for example a hole that is $5 \mathrm{\ \mu m}$ in diameter. This is “small” but it is still large enough for visible light to pass through. When visible light is inside then the E field is non-zero.

In principle, for any size hole there are wavelengths small enough to pass through, speaking classically and neglecting any quantum effects.

Answer (score 0):

The electric field does leak into holes, even at low frequencies. That's why if you increase the plate voltage of a vacuum triode, the current goes up. The field reaches through the holes in the grid, pulling electrons out of the charge cloud between the grid and cathode.